# Use of async/await in Jest unit tests raises an error in PhpStorm (or any JetBrains IDE)

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, phpstorm, jestjs, jetbrains-ide

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── lib
├── src
│   └── module.ts
├── tests
│   └── module.spec.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

I can write async/await code in the `src` dir, but when I try to use async/await syntax in unit test then my IDE (PhpStorm or any JetBrains product) complains that:

> TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor. Make sure you have a declaration form the 'Promise' constructor or include 'es2015' in your `--lib` options.

[image]

IMO this notice doesn't make sense because I have `"lib": ["es2017"]` in my `tsconfig.json`. But even If I replace it with `"lib": ["es2015"]` (which doesn't make sense, I know), then the error remains the same.

It's probably not a real error, because the code compiles properly and I can run the test.

Is it just a bug in the IDE or is it me doing something wrong?

---

### Update

I've just found that the problem is not related to async/await only. There's a similar problem with Promises. When I use the `Promise` constructor or `Promise.all()` then I get the following error:

> TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: In the settings of PhpStorm, section "Languages & Frameworks" → "TypeScript", check if "TypeScript Language Service" is checked.

Comment: Yes, I have. I've been also playing with "Compilation scope" settings. But I can't see any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json`, you have

```
"include": [
    "src"
  ]
```

so, only files from `src` folder are processed according to `tsconfig.json` settings; files from `tests` folder are excluded from compilation.
If PhpStorm can't find a `tsconfig.json` file your current file is included in, it uses default compilation settings - so `"lib": ["es2017"]` is not used when linting your spec files with Typescript service, and you see TS errors.

If you don't like to include test files in your main `tsconfig.json`, create a separate `tsconfig.json` with appropriate options in your `tests` folder: PhpStorm will use this config when linting your `*.spec.ts` files

Comment: Thanks, It works. I've wrongly assumed that the main `tsconfig.json` is used for the tests dir as well. 
In order not to repeat the whole config i use `"extends": "../tsconfig.json"` in `test/tsconfig.json`